# Decode on columns Null value

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have a table:

```
Shipment   Order_no   BOL_No
100        2332       <null>
101        <null>     4443
```

I want to decode on the null values of the columns. If the Order_no is null, it shows 'T' and if the Bol_No is null it shows 'P'.

How do I place decode on this column?

Answer (score 2):

Use NVL:

```
SELECT shipment, NVL(oder_no,'T'), NVL(bol_no,'P')
from table_name -- use the correct name
```

NVL returns the first argument, unless it is NULL in which case it gives the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Shipment, 
DECODE(Order_no, NULL, 'T') "Order_No",
DECODE(BOL_No, NULL, 'P') "BOL_No"
FROM `tablename`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
select shipment
     , nvl(order_no,'T') order_no
     , nvl(bol_no,'P')   bol_no
  from t
     ;
```

Watch out for datatype mismatches, you might need to convert column contents to varchar2 first:

```
select shipment
     , nvl(to_char(order_no),'T')   order_no
     , nvl(to_char(bol_no),  'P')   bol_no
  from t
     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with types.  Your columns look like numbers.  If so, you should explicitly convert them to strings:

```
select shipment,
       coalesce(cast(order_no as varchar2(255)), 'T') as order_no,
       coalesce(cast(bol_no as varchar2(255)), 'P') as bol_no
from t;
```

Relying on implicit conversion can introduce data errors that are really, really hard to find.

If they are already strings, then just use `coalesce()` (without the `cast()`).  `coalesce()` is the ANSI standard version of `nvl()`.